# How to capture error at compile level in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have route like

```
.bean(OrderService.class, "doSomething")
```

Now my question is if for any reason any developer misspell method name in route, we would not be able to identify at compile level or we may realize after going to production.

How to handle these scenario?

Comment: You should have test cases to handle this

Comment: Yes you are right, but still typo can be copied at that level. Any thing which camel support out of box.

Comment: No. In your test class, you should use this configuration class where you have the routes declared and not rewrite it

Comment: Either have a test or use try/catch to check the return value and if it is not set throw and error.

Comment: The Camel IDEA plugin has a feature to validate method names on your beans in the Java DSL: https://github.com/camel-tooling/camel-idea-plugin

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum I would recommend a test which ensures that your Camel components are registered with the Camel context, and if they're not, one would expect an exception to be thrown at application startup time.

In essence, you would want a Spring test suite (since Camel will leverage Spring's context for its own context) to ensure that your bean is wired in correctly here.

This cannot be a compile-time error or check since this is specific to how the application context is built, which is done dynamically at runtime.